# Enable F1-F12 keys without Fn on Lenovo Ideapad S400u

Tags: keyboard, lenovo-laptop, fn-key

I just have bought a new Lenovo Ideapad S400u notebook, and it is not default F1-F12, it is default mute button, refresh, more brightness, less brightness...

I've downloaded "Lenovo Keyboard Slim Fn Switcher" or something like that, but it didn't work.

Then, how can I change <kbd>Fn</kbd> function to get my F1-F12 buttons? I'm running Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the [Lenovo IdeaPad S300/S400/S400u/S405 User Guide V2.0](http://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/ideapad_s400u_ug_v2.0_aug_2012_english.pdf) (pdf) has what you want on page 12 in **Chapter 2. Learning the basics** where it says:

- **Setting hotkey mode**
   
  By default, the hotkey functions are accessible
  by pressing the appropriate hotkey. However, you can disable the
  hotkey mode in the BIOS setup utility.
  To disable the hotkey mode:

  1. Shut down the computer.
  2. Press the Novo button and then select BIOS Setup.
  3. In the BIOS setup utility, open the Configuration menu, and change the setting of **HotKey Mode** from **Enabled** to **Disabled**.
  4. Open the Exit menu, and select Exit Saving Changes.

<sub>Note: When hotkey mode is disabled, press the Fn key and the appropriate hotkey to access the corresponding hotkey function.</sub>

Comment: Why would Lenovo make this "swap feature" enabled by default? WHY? If you want to mess with my keys - make it optional! I accidently pressed F7 (Flight Mode, which disables wi-fi, the flag is not reset after reboot). It took me loooong time to dig to the reasons why my wi-fi card doesn't work...

Answer (score 19):

Shortest answer is the best ..[Lenovo website community](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/T400-T500-and-newer-T-series/T440-Reverse-FN-Key/td-p/1422663)

> Solution! Betreff: T440 - Reverse FN Key Options ‎02-02-2014 03:05 AM
>
> just press **"FN + ESC"**  once. There you'll have your single press F1... 
>   keys working.. 2 person found this solution to be helpful.

Now the light is on and then you can for example 
press the brightness,audio etc without
pressing **fn** every time

Comment: dear lord make more people like @shareef

Comment: Or have a look at the Lenovo guide at https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht103044-how-to-use-the-function-keys-without-pressing-fn-in-windows-8110.

Answer (score 2):

There is [a new BIOS update from Lenovo company](http://mobilesupport.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht080427). The problem was solved:

> **Symptom**
>   Some models of G/Z/P Series cannot achieve traditional function by pressing F1 to F12 directly.
>
> **Affected configurations**
>   The above symptom may occur to the following systems:
>
> - Lenovo G400\G500 with BIOS versions lower than V2.01
> - Lenovo G405s\G505s with BIOS versions lower than V2.03
> - Lenovo G400s\G500s with BIOS versions lower than V2.02
> - Lenovo Z400\Z500\P500 with BIOS Versions lower than V1.21
> - Lenovo G405\G505 with BIOS Versions lower than V2.04
> - Lenovo G410\G510 with BIOS Version lower than V2.01

See the above link for downloads. It says win8 but it's working in all windows versions.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to change this behavior in BIOS/UEFI. I couldn't google what key is used to enter BIOS setup in this specific laptop model, but you can try <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> on the manufacturer logo screen (immediately after you power it on, before OS starts to load).

Comment: I've tried to enter in BIOS, but I'm running the OS in a SSD, then it goes too fast, and i can't see it on startup :(

Comment: [This forum thread](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/IdeaPad-S-series-Netbooks/How-to-enter-BIOS-setup-in-IdeaPad-S10-s-boot-boost-mode/td-p/61246/page/3) suggests that there's some button you can press to boot into BIOS/UEFI. Windows 8[.1] is designed to skip BIOS screen if the hardware supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to hint from https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-reverse-the-function-key-on-Windows-10-laptop-Lenovo/answer/Vivek-Gurung-3
On Lenovo Edge 2-1580 laptop I've opened Lenovo Vantage (new version was installed)
and in Device menu opened "Input & Accessories",
then in "Intelligent Keyboard" panel
changed "Keyboard top-row function" to be "F1-F12 function"

Answer (score -1):

***Just a workaround, this is not answering the question as a whole. At least, it gives you direct access to F1-F12 again:***

Attach a second keyboard in order to use the F-keys. As a standard, the fn key will not be locked.
Use the main keyboard for fn-keys, and the second one for the F-keys.
(That is what I am doing even without your problem.)

p.s.:
In any case, always check again the options offered by Lenovo at https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht103044-how-to-use-the-function-keys-without-pressing-fn-in-windows-8110 to have the most recent guide.