# how to disable or reverse FN key: I want to replace: FN+F1 , FN+F2, FN+F3, ... FN+F12 with simply F1, F2, F3, ... F12

Tags: fn-key, lenovo-desktop-computer

Is there a way to replace FN-F2 with only F2 I restarted my PC and pressed FN-F12 or Fn-F1 and I didnt find configuration Tab to change from "Hotkey Mode" to "Legacy Mode".

all the tabs that I have are as follow

```
MAIN devices advanced power security startup and exit
```

I'm using Lenovo PC.

Is there a way to change it from command prompt directly?

So please any help what should I do?

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: Lenovo. Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM)  i3-3220 CPU @ 3.30GHz .
RAM: 2 GB .
System type: 64-bit

Comment: Assuming you're using Windows, open a command prompt, type or paste the following command and press Enter: `wmic csproduct get /format:list`. Then post there the command output.

Comment: yep I'm using windows.. 
I got something like this:
Caption=Computer System Product
Description=Computer System Product
IdentifyingNumber=PB3G...
Name=3485B...
SKUNumber=
UUID=....
Vendor=LENOVO
Version=ThinkCentre Edge72

Comment: The ThinkCentre Edge72 is a desktop model. Which keyboard are you using?

Comment: woooow thank you!! .. from your question I found the answer!! thank you soooooooooooooooooo much. I found a link while I was searching for the model number :))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable F1-F12 keys without Fn on Lenovo Ideapad S400u](https://superuser.com/questions/688343/enable-f1-f12-keys-without-fn-on-lenovo-ideapad-s400u)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this link and it was really helpful for me:

http://support.lenovo.com/pt_BR/downloads/detail.page?&LegacyDocID=MIGR-75582

I only followed the steps: i downloaded the zip file and extracted it. I installed it by clicking a double click on setup.exe

Now I can search from start - "Lenovo Slim USB Keyboard"

and just tick :

"Use F1-F12 as standard function keys"

:))

Thanks again for you @and31415 cz you let me found the key by searching for My keyboard model and I hope I will help the others with my answer

Comment: Lenovo usb keyboard driver works also in Win10-64bit even if download page did not say it. New background service is running but a small price for having an usable keyboard.

Answer (score 9):

You already have an answer, but I found easiest way to resolve the problem.

Just try press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> once and its should help :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer